# Attributes of GLMNET Library in R

Tags: r, csv, glmnet, lasso-regression

I was using the glmnet package in R, and I saved my input x, as a csv file. Its dimensions are: 34 by 8.I saved the output variable y as another csv file, and its dimensions were: 34 by 1

Code: x <- read.csv("input.csv")
      y <- read.csv("output.csv")

```
  model = glmnet(x,y)
```

This shows the following error:
Error in weighted.mean.default(y, weights) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length

I even tried: as.numeric(unlist(y)), to make sure y is a vector, but it doesn't seem to work. 
Can someone please tell me the error in my format for the attributes?

Comment: share some data so that one can reproduce your problem.

Comment: check `NROW(x)` and `NROW(y)`: are they definitely the same? Also you are passing a dataframe, when `glmnet` expects a matrix: look at the help pages `?glmnet`

Comment: For more specific help, you will need to edit your question with the results from `str(x)`, and `str(y)`

Comment: Any pointers on how I could save x, and y as matrices instead? dim(x), and dim(y) show that both have same number of rows (=34).

Comment: Thanks. It worked!